# Disable WebView scrolling in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms

I want to display a page with an image on top and with a WebView containing HTML text.

The problem is that WebView has its own scrolling so when user scrolls WebView is scrolling while image stays in place.

Is is possible to disable WebView scrolling? So image and WebView would scroll simultaneously.

I know that one solution is to embed image into HTML, but are there other solutions?

Comment: You can put a transparent View over your WebView (e.g. wrap them in `AbsoluteLayout`).

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: Hi @pfedotovsky , did you find any solution?

Comment: @marco.marinangeli, unfortunately, no. In my case it was possible NOT to  use WebView, so the solution was to get rid of WebView. Let me know if you find any solution for your case.

Answer (score 6):

Just set `Webview.IsEnabled` to *false*. It works when you don't have to interact with the Webpage.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow and thank you for trying to help. Please, for formatting, use ` backticks to highlight code.

Answer (score 2):

We faced the same issue. The best way we've found of doing this is to create a custom renderer for the WebView. [This page](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/25967/setting-height-of-webview-dynamically) outlines what is required for iOS and Android, but is lacking in Windows. This worked for us, hope this helps.